# How can widget show image

Tags: wordpress

I am writing a widget for showing an image via input the local path of the image. But stuck at the phase of showing image. Probably, the problem exists in the function: widget. I tried many ways, (you can see the code in the widget function), but still not working. Could some one point me the error?

```
<?php

        class oseBadgeWidget extends WP_Widget{

        public function oseBadgeWidget(){

            $widget_ops = array(
                'classname' => 'ose-badge-widget',
                'description' => 'Show the OSE Firewall Badget'
            );

            $control_ops = array(
                'width' => 200, 'height' => 250,
            );

            $this->WP_Widget('ose_Badge_Widget', 'OSE Badge Widget', $widget_ops, $control_ops);
        }

        public function __construct(){

            parent:: __construct(
                'ose_Badge_Widget',
                'OSE Badge Widget',
                array('description' => __('Show the OSE Firewall Badget'), )
            );  
        }


            // show the widget appearence
        public function form($instance){

            if (isset($instance['file_path'])){ $file_path = $instance[ 'file_path' ]; } else { $image_width = __( '', 'text_domain' ); }

        ?>
            <p>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('file_path' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'File Path:' ); ?></label> 
                    <input class="file_path" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'file_path' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'file_path' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $file_path ); ?>" />
            </p>

        <?php   
        }

        public function update($new_instance, $old_instance){

            $instance['file_path'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['file_path'] );

            return $instance;
        }

        // find the image from the input path, and show it
        public function widget($args, $instance){

            extract($args);

            if ($instance['file_path'] != ''){$file_path = $instance['file_path'];} else { $file_path = '';}

            $handle = opendir($file_path);
            $file = readdir($handle);

            echo $before_widget;

            echo '<img src= "picture/'.$file.'" border = "0" />';
            echo $after_widget;

            //$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/picture/');
            //$file = readdir($handle);


            //echo '<img src= "picture/'.$file.'" border = "0" />';
        }   
    }
    add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'register_widget( "oseBadgeWidget" );' ) );

?>
```

Comment: What exactly is issue ? 
p.s if you just want to show image in widget, why don't you put it as html in text/html widget available in wordpress ?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in a text widget and move the widget to where you want it to display.

```
<img src="URL OF IMAGE" alt="TEXT WHEN HOVERING OVER IT">
```

You can add further code such as width and height to alter the size of it as well.